# Gitlab is unable to fetch and display last commit and update commit columns on their website

Tags: gitlab

The gitlab UI doesn't display the "last commit" and "update commit" columns in the repository as can be seen in the image below. This is happening for all repositories. Everything else works fine. Can anyone explain what's happening here?

[image: bug in gitlab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed now. Must be a server issue.